# Get logs separately while invoking python script using a shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` script like below. In this I am passing table names from a file to the this script. The script is executing succesfully and I have no problem with the script.

Now I want to collect the logs of this script for each table indiviually. Is it possible?

`Pyspark` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
        print "Invalid number of args......"
        print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
        exit()
args_file = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

def mysql_spark(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password):

    print "*********************************************************table = {} ***************************".format(table)

    df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

    df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

input = sc.textFile('/user/XXXXXXXX/mysql_spark/%s' %args_file).collect()

for table in input:
 mysql_spark(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password)

sc.stop()
```

`Shell` script to invoke `pyspark` script

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/$USER/mysql_spark/source.sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }

args_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}

spark-submit --name "${args_file}" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/mysql_spark/mysql_spark.py ${args_file} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${mysqldb} ${username} ${password}


g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Spark job ${args_file} Execution"
```

`Questions`

```
I want to get the logs of each table separately as separate files rather than all the tables in a single file.

If possible the `status` messages of each table separately rather than getting single status message of file
```

`Log file`

```
*********************************************************table = table_1 ***************************
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/testing.db/table_1 on driver
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 4 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 2 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 4 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 71.6 KB, free 602.7 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.0 KB, free 627.7 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 530.2 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 4.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on localhost:59298 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8) in 121 ms on localhost (1/2)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7) in 133 ms on localhost (2/2)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 0.133 s
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 4 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.160750 s
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Using default output committer for Parquet: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Using user defined output committer class parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 1 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 5 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[15] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 84.4 KB, free 712.0 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 30.9 KB, free 742.9 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 30.9 KB, free: 530.1 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 5 (MapPartitionsRDD[15] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 5.0 with 1 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 9, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1922 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:37 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 30.9 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 9) in 2270 ms on localhost (1/1)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 2.270 s
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 5 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 2.302009 s
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201707261247_0000 committed.
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/testing.db/table_1 on driver
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 6 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 2 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 6 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[17] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_7 stored as values in memory (estimated size 71.6 KB, free 814.5 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_7_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.0 KB, free 839.5 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_7_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 530.1 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 7 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 6 (MapPartitionsRDD[17] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 6.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 10, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2101 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_7_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_7_piece0 in memory on localhost:59298 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 10) in 142 ms on localhost (1/2)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11) in 180 ms on localhost (2/2)
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 6.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 6 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 0.195 s
17/07/26 12:47:39 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 6 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.219934 s
*********************************************************table = table_2 ***************************
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/testing.db/table_2 on driver
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 7 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 2 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 7 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 7 (MapPartitionsRDD[21] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_8 stored as values in memory (estimated size 71.6 KB, free 911.1 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_8_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.0 KB, free 936.1 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_8_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 530.1 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 8 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 7 (MapPartitionsRDD[21] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 7.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 12, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 13, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_8_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_8_piece0 in memory on localhost:59298 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 13) in 69 ms on localhost (1/2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 12) in 137 ms on localhost (2/2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 7 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 0.138 s
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 7.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.157692 s
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Using default output committer for Parquet: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Using user defined output committer class parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 8 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 1 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 8 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 8 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9 stored as values in memory (estimated size 84.4 KB, free 1020.4 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 30.9 KB, free 1051.3 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_9_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 30.9 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 9 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 8 (MapPartitionsRDD[24] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 8.0 with 1 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 14, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1922 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_9_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 30.9 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 14) in 194 ms on localhost (1/1)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 8.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 8 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 0.195 s
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 8 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.221049 s
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO datasources.DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201707261247_0000 committed.
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://localhost/user/hive/warehouse/testing.db/table_2 on driver
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 9 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 2 output partitions
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 9 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 9 (MapPartitionsRDD[26] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10 stored as values in memory (estimated size 71.6 KB, free 1122.9 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 25.0 KB, free 1147.9 KB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_10_piece0 in memory on xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9612 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 10 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 9 (MapPartitionsRDD[26] at sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 9.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 15, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1975 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 16, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2101 bytes)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_10_piece0 in memory on localhost:63339 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_10_piece0 in memory on localhost:59298 (size: 25.0 KB, free: 3.1 GB)
17/07/26 12:47:40 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 15) in 124 ms on localhost (1/2)
17/07/26 12:47:41 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 16) in 151 ms on localhost (2/2)
17/07/26 12:47:41 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 9 (sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) finished in 0.158 s
17/07/26 12:47:41 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 9.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/26 12:47:41 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 9 finished: sql at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2, took 0.181504 s
```

Comment: You might want to consider simplifying your example code to the bare essentials. There is a lot of detail here which obscures the important parts of your issue.

Comment: Can you post the content of the log file that this script has created?

Comment: @alvarez The script prints one log file for table1 and then table2 and then table3 and so on. what I want is separate log files for each tables. Like table1.txt, table2.txt and so on

Comment: @Ashwini I understand this point. But would help a lot  view log file output for interpret how works your logger and try an approach to fit your requirements.

Comment: @alvarez Please check I have added sample logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you should read the file that contains the list of tables from bash script, and then send one spark-submit for each of them.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < args_file
for it in "${lines[@]}" 
do 
    TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
    touch /home/$USER/logs/${it}_${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
    touch /home/$USER/logs/${it}_${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
    success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${it}_${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
    failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${it}_${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

    #Function to get the status of the job creation
    function log_status
    {
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
    }   

    spark-submit --name "${it}" --master "yarn-client" /home/$USER/mysql_spark/mysql_spark.py ${it} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${mysqldb} ${username} ${password}
done
```

First argument of python script now is a table name:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
        print "Invalid number of args......"
        print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
        exit()
table = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

def mysql_spark(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password):

    print "*********************************************************table = {} ***************************".format(table)

    df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

    df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))


mysql_spark(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password)

sc.stop()
```

However, I do not know how this will affect the performance of the task.

Comment: Actually I have this script before itself. The reason I want to loop the table names in the `python` file is I want to use only one spark context, so I can minimize the time taken for the script to run for all the tables

Comment: @alvaraz If I do `spark-submit` for all the tables. It takes aroun `10-12` seconds for sparkcontext to be created and the run the script.

Comment: @Ashwini I figured it would not be a very efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Ashwini For perform this task from Python script, a possibility could be to redirect stdout output to a logger, which would have to be recreated at each iteration of the function to take the new file name. Another possibility would be to split the entire log file once the process is finished. Surely some partner with deeper knowledge of Python comes up with a more efficient way.

Comment: @Ashwini have you considered the ability to do the log configuration from the spark-submit script when launch the task? [ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html#configuring-logging)

Answer (score 0):

Just run your script as

```
./script.sh >> log.txt
```

Should save your logs in log.txt file. Anything and everything that your script prints out!

Comment: as you said it prints out only the print commands. What I want is separate log files for each time the script runs